# Integration over curve

Tags: integration, analysis, curves

I'm currently working on this problem :

> Consider the curve $\Gamma \subset R^3$ with parametrization $\gamma$ such that  : $$y(t):(r\cos t, r\sin t,ct)\quad  \forall t \in [0,b ]$$ where $c>0$ and $b$ is a real number. 
>   Compute : 
>   $$\int _{\Gamma}x_1dx_1+x_2dx_2+x_3dx_3$$

I know the definition of the integral over a curve $\Gamma\subset R^n$ with parametrization $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow \Gamma$, with $\gamma\in C^1([a,b])$
$$\int_{\Gamma}fds=\int_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\mid \dot \gamma(t)\mid dt$$
I don't know for this problem how to use this definition ? I mean, what is $f$ here ? 
Thanks for your help !

Comment: There are two different kinds of line integrals, the arclength line integral (whose definition you gave above) and the work line integral where you integrate the tangential component of a vector field. In your problem, the vector field is $\vec F = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$. You can write the work line integral in the other form by considering $f = \vec F \cdot \vec T$, where $\vec T$ is the unit tangent vector to the curve $\gamma$.

Comment: Ok so $\vec{F}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, so : $\int_{\Gamma}\vec{F}\cdot \ (dx_1,dx_2,dx_3)=\int_{a}^{b}\vec{F}(\gamma(t))\cdot \dot \gamma(t)dt$ ?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the formula for a scalar function. The fact that you have to integrate $x_1dx_1+x_2dx_2+x_3dx_3$ is a hint that your function is a vector function, so you need to use a slightly different formula. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field) is an example of what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

$x_1=r\cos t$ so $x_1dx_1=r\cos t (-r\sin t )dt $ and so forth. 
Your integral turns into a real integral of $\int f(t)dt $

Comment: But what is the definition of $\int_{\Gamma}f(t)dt$ then ?

Comment: Your integral is  work integral $$\int F(r).dr$$ where $F$ is  vector field and $r=<x,y,z>$ presents the path.